# How do i solve Permission error while startup

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.asish.gorai">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
    <application
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.InterstitialActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.VideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.LoaderActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.VideoPlayerActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.appodeal.ads.AppodealPackageAddedReceiver" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <data android:scheme="package" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.TestActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            tools:replace="android:theme" />

        <activity android:name="com.chartboost.sdk.CBImpressionActivity" android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

        <activity android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinInterstitialActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinConfirmationActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>

        <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.common.MoPubBrowser"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MraidVideoPlayerActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />
        <activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.RewardedMraidActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>

        <activity android:name="org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.activity.VASTActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>

        <activity android:name="org.nexage.sourcekit.vast.activity.VPAIDActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

        <activity android:name="com.appodeal.ads.networks.vpaid.VPAIDActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

        <activity android:name="com.amazon.device.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"/>

        <activity android:name="com.my.target.ads.MyTargetActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>

        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" />

        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.ads.list3d.List3DActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.adsCommon.activities.OverlayActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.adsCommon.activities.FullScreenActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <service android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.common.metaData.PeriodicMetaDataService" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <service android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.common.metaData.InfoEventService" />
        <receiver android:name="com.startapp.android.publish.common.metaData.BootCompleteListener" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>


        <service android:name="com.yandex.metrica.MetricaService" android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" android:process=":Metrica"
            android:permission=""
            tools:ignore="ExportedService">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <action android:name="com.yandex.metrica.IMetricaService" />
                <data android:scheme="metrica" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="metrica:api:level" android:value="58" />
        </service>
        <receiver android:name="com.yandex.metrica.MetricaEventHandler"
            android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"
            android:permission=""
            tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.yandex.mobile.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.ads.adunit.AdUnitSoftwareActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.ads2.adunit.AdUnitActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.ads2.adunit.AdUnitSoftwareActivity"
            android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" android:hardwareAccelerated="false" />

        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyOverlay"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyFullscreen"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.jirbo.adcolony.AdColonyBrowser"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.flurry.android.FlurryFullscreenTakeoverActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.flurry.android.FlurryShareActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.flurry.android.FlurryTileAdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.flurry.android.FlurryBrowserActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <activity android:name="com.mobvista.msdk.offerwall.view.MVOfferWallActivity"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.mobvista.msdk.offerwall.view.MVOfferWallRewardVideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.mobvista.msdk.reward.player.MVRewardVideoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.mobvista.msdk.videofeeds.vfplayer.VideoFeedsActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity android:name="com.mobvista.msdk.out.LoadingActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.mobvista.msdk.interstitial.view.MVInterstitialActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <activity android:name="com.mobvista.msdk.shell.MVActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />

        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.tapjoy.TJAdUnitActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.tapjoy.mraid.view.ActionHandler" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.tapjoy.mraid.view.Browser" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.tapjoy.TJContentActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />

        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.ControllerActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.InterstitialActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.ironsource.sdk.controller.OpenUrlActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.adcolony.sdk.AdColonyInterstitialActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
        <!--suppress AndroidDomInspection -->
        <activity android:name="com.adcolony.sdk.AdColonyAdViewActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>

        <activity android:name="com.inmobi.rendering.InMobiAdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard|smallestScreenSize|screenSize|screenLayout"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:resizeableActivity="false" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
            tools:targetApi="n" />
        <receiver android:name="com.inmobi.commons.core.utilities.uid.ImIdShareBroadCastReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"
            android:permission=""
            tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.inmobi.share.id"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!--optional, remove if not using Ogury-->
        <activity android:name="io.presage.activities.PresageActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="io.presage.intent.action.LAUNCH_WEBVIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!--optional, remove if not using Ogury-->
        <receiver android:name="io.presage.receiver.AlarmReceiver" />
        <!--optional, remove if not using Millennial Media-->
        <provider
            android:name="com.millennialmedia.internal.utils.MediaContentProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.MediaContentProvider"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity android:name="com.asish.gorai.Permission"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.asish.gorai.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.asish.gorai.SecondActivity"
            android:label="10 Best Foods for Keeping Your Skin Healthy" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.asish.gorai.SecondActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.asish.gorai.ThirdActivity"
            android:label="10 Best  Foods for Diabetes and Blood Sugar">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.asish.gorai.FrothActivity"
            android:label="10 Best Foods for Babies">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.asish.gorai.FiveActivity"
            android:label="10 Best Foods for Pregnancy">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.asish.gorai.SixdActivity"
            android:label="10 Best Foods for Osteoarthritis">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.asish.gorai.SevenActivity"
            android:label="10 Best Foods for Better Eyesight">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.asish.gorai.EightActivity"
            android:label="10 Best Foods for Blood Pressure">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.asish.gorai.NineActivity"
            android:label="10 Best Foods for Hair Health">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.asish.gorai.TenActivity"
            android:label="10 Best Foods for Weight Loss">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.asish.gorai.ElevenActivity"
            android:label="10 Best Foods for Liver Health">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

After generating app from source code two error message displayed although it does not affect the app by any mean, but it really looks odds when someone open my app and those ugly errors shown before start the apps.

**Error :-**

> 1. missing permission , uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE # although i
>      gave the permission #
> 2. Integration Error : Vungle classes are already loaded from jar files ,remove unnecessary Dex files. # i use Appodeal SDK integration
>      #

i just can't understand what should i have to do, please help me.

Comment: show your manifest file

Answer (score 2):

about case one add this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

above application tag in manifest

Comment: as i told i already gave the permission though the error msg triggers

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked their [documentation?.](https://www.appodeal.com/sdk/documentation) Also, look through the samples, if you are using MultiDex or if you are not using MultiDex, as there are different sample projects for these. In the app folder, look for the proguard-rules.pro and copy the rules there.